# Extended classes and Static members in java

Tags: java, class, encapsulation

Was experimenting with java, testing out how things work and discovered that static variables declared in a superclass do not get reinitialised in subclasses derived from a superclass using *extends*.

I discovered this while trying to do a create a count of instances and found it strange that I was getting total count for the superclass and all its subclasses.

I have searched for a reason for why this is, as honestly it seems a bit strange in terms of encapsulation, but have failed to find any explanation.  Is there some logical reason why java classes were created this way or am I thinking about things completely wrong?

Comment: `static` members are not inherited.

Comment: statics are just like that. static

Comment: static fields and methods are bound to a class, not to an instance of the class. As such, these fields/methods are not affected by any inheritance.

Comment: it means there's, like, only one

Answer (score 0):

The right mental model for `static` stuff is: **They do not exist as part of a class at all!**.

But, why are they declared in a class, then? The answer: *namespaces*.

All programming systems, pretty much, need the concept of *namespaces*.  Without namespaces, if you name one method `indexOf`, then nothing else in the entire system can use that name, which means the very concept of having libraries written by others you can import is either impossible or at least very tricky. Either the community kludges around this sad state of affairs by naming their stuff `foo_bar_projectname_indexOf` instead, or it's a toy language that you can't meaningfully expand without almost immediately running into conflicts.

Java solved this problem with.... classes. Or rather, types. Classes get the benefit of existing in packages, and thus conflicts are impossible for them. Then, methods (and fields and constructors) are in classes, and thus, everything is namespaced.

Hence, static stuff are best thought of existing on their own, but, you must declare them in classes because if you didn't, what namespace are they even in?

Hence, if you define e.g.:

```
class Parent {
  static int counter;
}

class Child {}
```

The right mental model is: `counter` is a variable that has nothing to do with any class in the first place. To 'access' it, it piggybacks on `Parent`'s namespace: You access this field via the `Parent` class, but it isn't *of* the parent class.

Hence, `Child` does not get its own `counter` - in the above mental model, why would it?

Another way this mental model works well: You simply **cannot** override static methods. At all. The mental model of "static things exist independent of classes" correctly predicts this; it doesn't even make sense to talk about overriding when the thing exists separate from the class it is in.

Comment: Then why permit Child.staticMember to simply point to Parent.staticMember?  Seems silly if it is about the namespace.  It is now in every extended class's namespace and can't be used for anything useful.

Comment: `Child.staticMember` is still about namespacing; java doesn't "do" dynamic dispatch for static stuff, it can't, because - they aren't really 'of' their class. There are a few dubious aspects to it all which can only be ascribed to careless language design in 1.0 and unwillingness (probably justified unwillingness) to break backwards compatibility to 'fix' it. There's an obvious ocean of difference between claiming all `indexOf` in all classes everywhere, and 'merely' in your class + all things that extend it.